# Certificate missing when Azure API Manager calls Azure APP Service

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

When I call my API from API Management (APIM) I do not see the certificate in the RequestContext or the header.

---

I have the following settings:

My App uses a Service Plan on Pricing Tier: Basic: 1 Small

I am on the Developer Program Benefit subscription

Which I believe means I have access to use Certificates

---

I uploaded the certificate to:
Azure | APIM Instence | Publisher Portal | Security | Client Certificates

For the site

```
"clientCertEnabled": true,
```

For the API scope

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <authentication-certificate thumbprint="58D06D6E3265F6AE841527ABDF721F260871B6A5" />
</inbound>
```

APIM exposes the HTTPS URI of the API

---

I use this code in my AuthorizeAttribute class to read the certificate from the Request:

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var cert = actionContext.RequestContext.ClientCertificate;
```

And I use this in a controller Action:

```
X509Certificate2 clientCertInRequest = RequestContext.ClientCertificate;
```

---

I believe that all of this was working earlier in the week but as I am trying Azure out I wrote down what I did, destroyed my setup and started from scratch to test my understanding.

Now I'm stuck.

What have I missed out/done wrong?

Comment: Are you using a https ServiceURL?

Comment: Ah, that was it.  
I ticked HTTPS for Web API URL scheme so I expected the Web service URL to have detected that and changed.
It doesn't.  I guess it's a bug.

Comment: We allow the front end to be HTTPS and the backend to be HTTP, or vise versa.  I've made the same mistake before though.  Perhaps we can identify if you upload a certificate that you need to be using a HTTPS backend.

Comment: I added an answer just so we can keep track of which questions have been addressed and which haven't :-)

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that the 2 settings referred to different URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backend Service URL also needs to be an HTTPS URL.